# Rendering DOM contents to Canvas

Tags: html, internet-explorer, dom, canvas

I have couple of html elements (div/span etc.) I want to be able my HTML5 Canvas to read that html and render it as it is. Later on I will convert it into bytes with the help of `canvas.toDataURL()` and save as an image

I am not looking for plug-in based solutions and this is specifically targeted to IE9/10
Appreciate any help towards this !!

Comment: Mostly you get blocked from doing this sort of thing by security/privacy restrictions.

Comment: That is not the concern for me, as this would not be a public page

Comment: It is a concern for you because the browser won't care whether or not you think it's a public page, it will endeavour to protect your privacy and security anyway.

Comment: Even though you say no, I still would suggest a plug-in.  **Are you really willing to create an html parser from scratch** to analyze your div?  Alternatively, since you appear to have a captive user base, how about just distributing a screen capture app?

Answer (score 1):

You can perhaps use this solution:

https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas

```
html2canvas( [ document.body ], {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        /* canvas is the actual canvas element,
           to append it to the page call for example
           document.body.appendChild( canvas );
        */
        }
});
```

Note: If images are loaded from non-origin (and doesn't have accept header set) it won't show up.

Optionally you can use your server as a proxy to fetch the images and serve them to client:

```
<img src="http://myserver.com/getexternalimage?http....
```